# where should I ask for help with drupal?

Tags: discussion

I have a copermine gallery on my site and on copermine forum you can ask any question you want.

Is not the same with drupal.I hade 2 questions and they were deleted.Why? What is with off topic thing?Can not ask a question on a module issue.Nobody answers there.I want it to ask a question about setting on the host for subdomain module and users opinion about a host I choosed for drupal. How is that off topic? Drupal Answers shoud be about everything you need to know to make your drupal site work how you want.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, welcome :)

This sort of question does come up for new users occasionally, not just here but all across the Stack Exchange network. The most important thing to realise is that this *isn't* a forum, it's a repository of high quality questions and answers about Drupal. To make sure things stay focused on the topics we want to cover here, we have to enforce certain rules with regard to subject/content/quality.

I'm not going to re-hash the entirety of that here, the best advice I can give is to read through the following

- [The about page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/about), which outlines what this site is all about, and (importantly) how it differs from a forum. It also contains examples of questions and subjects that we consider on/off topic here.
- [The help centre](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help), which contains links to more specific details about types of questions that it's appropriate to ask here, as well as lots more information about the site and Stack Exchange network in general.

To address the title of your question briefly

> where should I ask for help with drupal?

If you have specific, objectively answerable questions about Drupal, then this is the place.

If you're looking for opinions, tutorials, to report bugs in modules, help with setting up a web server, general PHP, general jQuery, etc, then this isn't the place.

There's a bit more to it than that (which you can find in the about/help pages), and I've just picked some random examples of off-topic content, but generally speaking that's accurate.

Just to address this point

> Drupal Answers shoud be about everything you need to know to make your drupal site work how you want.

I'm afraid that isn't (and can't be) the case. In order to maintain the quality of the content here we have to limit the scope of the site. This is true of all sites in the network, and the model has proven to be so successful I doubt the powers that be would consider changing it.